# Why is STATUS_OUT_OF_ORDER_API_CALL thrown when trying to send a payload?

Tags: android, google-nearby

I am trying to send a bytes payload from an advertiser to a discoverer after the connection has successfully been established (`STATUS_OK` in `onConnectionResult()`), but I am getting a `STATUS_OUT_OF_ORDER_API_CALL` error (error 8009). How do I fix this?

From the documentation page on [status codes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsStatusCodes.html), I know that there is a method that I should be calling first, but I don't what method that is.

I have seen the ["How to resolve STATUS_OUT_OF_ORDER_API_CALL error?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037972/how-to-resolve-status-out-of-order-api-call-error) on this issue. The accepted answer says that you could get the error if trying to connect to someone after disconnecting. This issue is when I first open the app and try to send a payload, and I am not getting the `API_CONNECTION_FAILED_ALREADY_IN_USE` or `STATUS_ALREADY_ADVERTISING` status code in `onConnectionResult()`. Also, that post was to do with receiving the error when trying to request the connection, whereas in my situation, both advertiser and discoverer have connected fine.

```java
if (isAdvertising) {
    Log.d(TAG, "send: advertising fine");
}

connectionsClient
    .sendPayload(endpointId, payload)
    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.w(TAG,
                 "(send payload) onFailure: " + failureMsg, e) )
    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Log.w(TAG,
                 "(send payload) onSuccess: " + successMsg));
```

The strange part is that from the the first payload I try to send works, but subsequent payloads don't get sent.

Error message:

```
2019-04-03 19:14:13.535 31128-31128/com.example.adhocdisplay W/ConnectionsActivity: (send payload) onFailure: Failed to send calibration direction payload
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8009: STATUS_OUT_OF_ORDER_API_CALL
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nearby.zzby.setFailedResult(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nearby.zzba.zzc(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nearby.zzea.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.nearby.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:22)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

Comment: I think it's unlikely for the problem to be fixed based on the code I've provided alone, but I don't know what else to include. Please let me know if there is something else and I'll happily include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work on Nearby

This error shouldn't occur in normal use... It means that we've lost track of the strategy you're using. This could be because you called stopAllEndpoints or somehow disconnected from our service (note: not the same as disconnecting from the remote device). Or it could be a consequence of trying to mix and match strategies (eg. CLUSTER, STAR, POINT_TO_POINT).

The good news is that this particular error condition was removed in a recent submission and will be rolled out to devices somewhat soon. But I'm still a bit stumped as to how you ran into it.

Comment: I'll have a look into why I could be disconnecting from your service. I'm not calling stopAllEndpoints() (I was calling it in onBackPressed() and onStop(), but I commented that out and the problem persists) or mixing strategies (I have the strategy defined as a constant)

Comment: You were right about me calling stopAllEndpoints(). I was calling it in onStop(), but I forgot onStop() was called when I load in an image via an explicit intent